# При сборке проекта возникает ошибка об отсутствии пакета, как его установить?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

При попытке собрать чужое решение в *.dll, вылазит ошибка об отсутствии пакета .NET Standard 2.0

`warning NU1701: Пакет "Rocket.Unturned 5.0.0.236" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8", а не целевой платформы проекта ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом.`

Как его установить?

Comment: Тут проблема в совместимости, текущая версия этой либы совместима с .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 это версия .NETStandard совместима с .NET Framework 4.6.1с некоторыми оговорками. Смотрите тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Странно, но у вас версия 5.0.0.236, он напрямую должна поддерживать .NET Framework 4.6.1 какая у вас версия целевой платформы проекта ?

Comment: @PavelPopov http://screenshot.ru/8631dcfe9ec7dbb4c7cbdd608d80a6fa.png

Comment: @PavelPopov т.к. я новичок, я слегка не понимаю в чем именно суть данной ошибки. Этот проект - плагин, скачанный с GitHub для игрового сервера, базирующегося на C#. Мне сейчас нужно, чтобы эти сообщения о несовместимости вообще исчезли.

Comment: а т.е. ваш проект под .NETStandard,Version=v2.0, а эта либа под .NET Framework 4.6.1, тогда можете в нагете попробовать поставить Rocket.Unturned последней версии, она ка раз под .NETStandard,Version=v2.0